# Dynamically Resizing UICollectionViewLayout ReRenders Layers in iOS10

Tags: uicollectionviewlayout, ios10

When implementing a UICollectionViewLayout. If you invalidate the layout, then recreate the attributes in prepare(), the cells are still rendering the old layers in when they are reused. Or the collectionView is rendering incorrectly. It only happens in iOS10. It rendered correctly in prior versions. It does not occur when the the sizes are constant.

And I am unable to clear them in prepareForReuse or layoutSubviews of the collectionView.

```
class PortfolioDisplayFlowLayout: UICollectionViewLayout {

    var cache  = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()

    // amount the user need to scroll before the feature cell changes
    let dragOffset:CGFloat = 180

    // return item index of currently featured cell
    var featuredItemIndex:Int {
        get {
            return max(0, Int(collectionView!.contentOffset.y / dragOffset))
        }
    }

    var headerItemIndex:Int {
        get {
            return 0
        }
    }

    // return value between 0-1 that represents how close the next cell is to be featured
    var nextItemPercentageOffset:CGFloat {
        get {
            return (collectionView!.contentOffset.y / dragOffset) - CGFloat(featuredItemIndex)
        }
    }

    // math helpers
    var numberOfItems:Int {
        get {
            return collectionView!.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)
        }
    }

    var width : CGFloat {
        get {
            return collectionView!.bounds.width
        }
    }

    var height : CGFloat {
        get {
            return collectionView!.bounds.height
        }
    }


    // MARK: UICollectionViewLayout
    override func prepare() {
        cache.removeAll(keepingCapacity: false)
        invalidateLayout()
        let standardHeight:CGFloat = 100
        let featuredHeight:CGFloat = 280

        var frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0)
        var y: CGFloat = 0

        for item in 0..<numberOfItems {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(item:item, section:0)
            let attributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forCellWith: indexPath)

            attributes.zIndex = item
            var height = standardHeight

            if indexPath.item == featuredItemIndex {
                let yOffset = standardHeight * nextItemPercentageOffset
                y = collectionView!.contentOffset.y - yOffset
                height = featuredHeight
            } else if indexPath.item == (featuredItemIndex + 1) && indexPath.item != numberOfItems {
                let maxY = y + standardHeight
                height = standardHeight + max((featuredHeight - standardHeight) * nextItemPercentageOffset, 0)
                y = maxY - height
            }

            frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: y, width: width, height: height)
            attributes.frame = frame
            cache.append(attributes)
            y = frame.maxY
        }
    }

    override func shouldInvalidateLayout(forBoundsChange newBounds: CGRect) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForItem(at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? {
        return cache[indexPath.row]
    }

    override func layoutAttributesForElements(in rect: CGRect) -> [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]? {
        var layoutAttributes = [UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes]()
        for attributes in cache {
            if attributes.frame.intersects(rect) {
                layoutAttributes.append(attributes)
            }
        }
        return layoutAttributes
    }

    override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
        let contentHeight = (CGFloat(numberOfItems) * dragOffset) + (height - dragOffset)
        return CGSize(width: width, height: contentHeight)
    }
}
```

Here is a screen shot of the collectionView in iOS 10
[image: Here is a screen shot of the collectionView in iOS 10]

Here is a screen shot of the collectionView in iOS 9
[image: Here is a screen shot of the collectionView in iOS 9]

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer with Apple latest [WWDC](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/219/). New property `isPrefetchingEnabled` on the collectionView has to be set to false if you are changing the cell sizes while scrolling. Its set to true by default.

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    collectionView?.isPrefetchingEnabled = false
}
```